# can't transform $_get variables in url to slashes in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get (as many people before me have) my url with a particular $_get variable to mod_rewrite into slashes.

[the latest post i have used among many others to no avail;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229222/turn-text-after-slashes-into-variables-with-htaccess)

My original Code (thanks to Prix) Which gives me - www.mydomain.com/Events?var=data:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.(html|phtml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ $1.html [L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.phtml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.phtml -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ $1.phtml [L]
```

The Code/s i have tried and none have worked:

```
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ Events.php?e=$1 [QSA,L]

#RewriteRule ^Events/(.*)$ Events.phtml?Event=$1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^Events/(.*)$ Events?Event=$1 [QSA,L]

#RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$  .phtml?$1=$2
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  Events.phtml?$1=$2 [L]

#RewriteRule ^Events/(.*)/?$ Events.phtml?p=$1
```

As you can see in simple form am trying to get `www.mydomain.com/Events.phtml?Event=data` to rewrite to `www.mydomain.com/Events/data` .

I'm getting there but still do not understand the code entirely, which is obviously why i cannot get it to work;

What am i doing wrong!

**NOTE:** 
- I am happy to use just one variable for all get variables that i may need to pass and parse with php.
- Events is **not** the only page i would like to do this on.
- It needs to work in subfolders so it works when demonstrating or developing in wamp localhost;

Comment: Please, don't use the word "sexy" here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: apologies I only used it because if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825252/htaccess-sexy-url-rewrites